# How to link to a particular answer?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distinguishing between questions and answers in references.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/distinguishing-between-questions-and-answers-in-references)

In the past, if I've encountered a particularly good answer to a question, and later found a question for which said answer could prove useful, I've simply linked to the previous question, and specified the user whose answer I intended to share.

Recently, I saw a post where somebody linked to a particular answer, and I'd love to be able to do that, myself, but can't for the life of me find that post, or any other instances of linking to answers. Can someone instruct me?

Comment: Ah! Right you are, Jonas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next to the voting arrows for each answer, it says "[link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3588/7850) edit flag".

Comment: Thanks! ${}{}{}{}$