# help with what is my user id and how do i check it?

Tags: support

what is my user id and how to check it?

i'm trying to run `posts.OwnerUserId = ##UserId##` but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Where do you run the command?

Comment: @Tim I guess he wants to use [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: thanks, @MartinSleziak!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click on your username, you will get to your [profile page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39743/user133466).

Your user id is the number contained in that link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39743/user133466

In your case 39743.

Note that your user id for your accounts on different SE sites can be different.

P.S.
When using [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), don't forget that the data may not be up to date - they are from the last data dump.

Comment: I will include a link to the same question on Meta Stack Exchange: [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771)