# Why is the user:me search function works (while I am logged in) but when I log out and search user:StephenElliott or user:Stephen Elliott dosen't work

Tags: support, search, display-names, users

I want to be able to share my Questions and Answers with friends and family, but I do not want to give them my account password, of course.

I can search for my questions and answers successfully while logged in using the search field **user:me** as documented.  I think that my user name is **Stephen Elliott** or **StephenElliott** but when I try to search with **user:Stephen Elliott** or **user:StephenElliott** I get thousands of results, none of which seems relevant to my recent posts.

Here are screenshots clarifying the difficulty, first with the user name of **Stephen Elliott** here:

[image: Image of search with user name Stephen Elliott]

And next is the search screen shot with the user name of **StephenElliott** here:

[image: Image of search with user name StephenElliott]

Below is the screenshot search of **user:456735** that works fine:

[image: image of search using user:456735]

I did notice that if I use **user:456735** that the search seems to work fine.  But it is much more convenient if I can share my user name instead of a number, because it is easier for my friends and family to remember the user name (of course if that works).

Also, for me, it is difficult for me to remember this user number.  Where can the user number be found?  I was unable previously to find it with the user profile?  Is there any insight about this? Do I need to put the user name in quotations or something?  What do I need to do to search based on the actual user name that is associated with the post?

I appreciate the community's support to resolve this issue.

Comment: Usernames can be changed. User ID cannot. If they really care that much, sharing the direct link should be far more effective than telling them several instructions on where to search.

Comment: As for finding the user ID, click on the profile, it's right there in the URL. You cannot search using a user name because they are neither unique nor permanent.

Comment: Related posts on [meta.se]: [Search on username](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92148) and [Allow searching by user name in searches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189715).

Comment: @Nij: Thank you for the insight about how I can get the ID number.  That is great!  The other question, though, is that if I am not logged in, is there a way for me to search for my profile.  It seems that for Stack Exchange generally, there is a Users page to search, starting with the specific Stack Exchange Site and finishing with **/users**.  For example, for this site, there is [User's Page Here math.stackexchange.com/users](https://math.stackexchange.com/users).  The picture should be enough to share the reference.  Thank you for your support!  (Also, should I thus answer the question?)

Comment: On this meta: [Help with what is my user id and how do I check it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6598)
On [meta.se]: [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771)

Comment: Often it may be difficult to view profile URL on a mobile device (especially in portrait mode). In that case just click on the search button on profile page and you should see the phrase "user:<numerid user id>" by default in the search box.