# Organizing The MathJax Tutorial

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

There is a wonderful post dedicated to MathJax code found here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

The only problem I see with this post is that the additional contents below the original post are not easily accessible from the main post. For example, if you were only interested in figuring out how to type matrix notation then you would have to scroll down until you find it, or perhaps try a keyword search. I think that it could be a lot more user friendly if there was something of a table of contents amended to the original post that could essentially provide a hyperlink to the posts below where users have contributed substantially.

I am just wondering if there is a way to hyperlink to the comments below. In my downtime I think it would be fun to organize, but not sure if Math Meta has that type of capability?

Comment: Do you mean something similar to the clickable "table of content" included in this question: [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) (Needless to say, in the post with so much MathJax, the links to answer might not work perfectly; at least not until all MathJax has been "compiled".)

Comment: As a side note, I suppose you want to ask about links to *answers* rather than links to *comments*.

Comment: One reason that I think the said post is useful is because it is not that organized. They give a kick start to people who had never used latex, so that (by reading the question without reading the answers) they can type decently in main. If it is a too organized, then it becomes a user manuel, instead of a quick help.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak For clarity, yes you're right in regards to the answers. For example, the first answer is "matricies" while the second one was "aligning equations" So I thought it could be beneficial as a reference just to have a list of the categories that people have contributed already. In that regard, the post would sort of function as a reference material.

Comment: For details on how to get link to an answer, see: [Distinguishing between questions and answers in references.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3586). (Comments are not relevant for this particular issue, but since they have been mentioned: [How to link to a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1816))

Comment: I'm the original writer of the MJ tutorial.  I think your idea is good.  What if you were to add a list of links at the bottom of the main post, linking to the most important of the sub-articles?  I think it would fit in perfectly right at the end, just after the part of the main article that instructs people to create addenda.

Comment: If you want help doing it, [people in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64952/math-meta-chat) will probably be willing to advise.

Comment: @MJD Yeah I think that we are on the same page in regards to the execution.

Comment: is @MJD short for mathjax demonstrator ?

Comment: Update: I have amended the original post that includes about 5 links to what I would say are the more important aspects of the MathJax post.